# This simple Mutex does not have any effect

Tags: c++, mutex

I am trying to learn basics of multi-threading. Below example is from the book "Art of Multiprocessor Programming" which has (in Java):

```
class Counter
{
    private long value;
    private Lock lock;

    public long getAndIncrement()
    {
        lock.lock();
        try
        {
            long temp = value;
            value = temp + 1;
            return temp;
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock();            
        }
    }
}
```

end of java code. The book says "lock() and unlock()" shown above will add mutual exclusion to this shared counter implementation. (I am unable to run this java code myself and also think "value" should be returned rather than "temp".)

when I tried this simple example (in C++ which I can try) my mutex is not doing anything. I can remove it, results will be the same.
c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

class Counter
{
public:
    Counter(int v)
    : value(v)
    {}

    int getAndIncrement()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
        return value++;
    }

    void show() const
    {
        std::cout << "value = " << value << '\n';
    }

private:
    int value;
    std::mutex m;
};

int main()
{
    Counter c1(1);

    std::thread t1(&Counter::getAndIncrement, &c1);
    t1.detach();
    c1.show(); // 1 or 2

    std::thread t2(&Counter::getAndIncrement, &c1);
    t2.detach();
    c1.show(); // 1 or 2

    //int n = c1.getAndIncrement();
    //std::cout << n << '\n'; // 1 or 2 or 3. never 4

    c1.getAndIncrement();
    c1.show(); //2, 3 and sometimes 4
}
```

Comments show my outputs when I run the code. My mutex has no effect.
Any guide would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: what output did you expect and why? I don't understand what effect of the mutex you expect to observe in this code

Comment: I'm expecting 4. Because I'm thinking each thread that enters "getAndIncrement()" should first lock (and block other threads entering at the same time), perform a ++ operation, then unlock it so next thread can do the same.

Comment: threads take time to spin up.  It quite possible you call `show` before the thread even starts.

Comment: @mhm There is no guarantee that these threads will get the mutex in any particular order. All the mutex guarantees is that no two threads will execute `value++` and compute their return values at the same time or overlapping.

Comment: Looks like it is working perfectly. What affect were you expecting that is not happening? Based on your comment you expect the `main()` thread to read the value last (after all increments have been done). But you have done nothing to prevent the main thread running ahead and print the values before the other threads do anything. The threads can increment the counter some time later. It is quite possible for this code to print `0` every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect of the mutex should be to make sure no two threads are simultaneously reading or writing to the member (only reading is fine). In your code thats not the case because at the same time one thread locked the mutex and writes to the member the main thread might call `show`. You need to protect any access:

```
void show() const
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
    std::cout << "value = " << value << '\n';
}
```

Then your code is fine and the output you observe is to be expected.

You are starting 2 threads and you cannot know if first those threads write or first main reads from the member.

Possible sequence is:

```
  thread t1 writes
  main calls show          2
  main calls show          2
  main increments
  main calls show          3
  thread t2 writes
```

another possible sequence is:

```
  main calls show          1
  main calls show          1
  thread t2 writes         
  thread t1 writes
  main increments
  main calls show          4
```

The mutex only protects concurrent access to the member. You can be certain that this will happen in order:

```
  main calls show
  main calls show
  main increments
  main calls show
```

If you want things to happen in a particular order also between different threads, you need to add some sort of synchronisation (eg. a condition variable). Though for your simple example that would basically correspond to no parallelism and adding the threads would merely add overhead.

---

> So final value of "value" is not supposed to be 4

Lets remove the `detach`s from your code and add some `join`s:

```
int main()
{
    Counter c1(1);

    std::thread t1(&Counter::getAndIncrement, &c1);
    c1.show(); // 1 or 2

    std::thread t2(&Counter::getAndIncrement, &c1);
    c1.show(); // 1 or 2 or 3

    c1.getAndIncrement();
    c1.show(); // 2, 3 or 4
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    c1.show(); // definitely 4 !!!
}
```

`join` waits for the thread to finish. That is: we can be sure that by the time `join` returns, the thread already returned from `getAndIncrement`. The last `show` definitely prints `4`. In a simpler example:

```
int main()
{
    Counter c1(1);

    std::thread t1(&Counter::getAndIncrement, &c1);
    c1.show(); // 1 or 2

    t1.join();
    c1.show(); // 2
}
```

---

PS: I am still not completely certain what your misunderstanding really is/was. Consider that multithreaded is not just single-threaded + threads. Its part of the design. Often different algorithms or data-structures must/should be used.

Comment: So final value of "value" is not supposed to be 4? Because 3x ++ operations are called..

Comment: I'd recommend leaving the io out of the guarded area in this case: `void show() const { int valueLocal; {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m); valueLocal = value;}
    std::cout << "value = " << valueLocal << '\n';
}`

Comment: final is 4 even with detaching instead of joining? @fabian why?

Comment: @mhm you want to do as little as possible in critical sections to keep the time other threads need to wait for a release of the lock to a minimum. Copying the field value is fast, writing it to stdout is not as fast, so destroying the `lock_guard` before writing is preferrable.

Comment: Thank you all. @fabian  Thanks.